# sort a dictionary <object, List<int>> c#

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I would like to sort a list of objects, The structure is a `Dictionary<Object, List<int>>`

items in the dictionary would be

```
item_1, (2,2,3)
item_2, (1,3,4)
item_3, (2,3,4)
item_4, (1,2)
```

once the items are sorted they should appear as

```
item_4, 1,2
item_2, 1,3,4
item_1, 2,2,3
item_3, 2,3,4
```

so, essentially I have to sort on the first item in the list, then the second item, then the 3rd items, what would be an easy way of implementing such a solution using linq

Comment: Are the items in the `value` of your dictionary garunteed to be ordered or must you order them the same time you want to order the keys? Also, do you want the dictionary to be constantly order or just order it on demand when you need to print it out once and a while. If you want constant ordering your dictionary will be slower and you will need to use something like a `OrderedDictionary`

Comment: items in the value would first need to be ordered, it would need to be ordered on demand

Comment: Should the ordering of the items effect the `List<int>` that is stored? Also, if I have `item_5, (1,2,3)` which item goes first, Item_4 or Item_5? Lastly, can you garuntee that the items in the `List<int>` are presorted? if you can it makes the problem a LOT easier.

Comment: List<int> is simply a convenience - essentially, the view model is being passed to the view and the sorting is being done in the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a custom comparer that can compare a sequence of values based on the items in that sequence, rather than based on the reference to the sequence itself (given that most sequences don't override the default equality behavior).  This is fairly straightforward:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IComparer<T> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        using (var first = x.GetEnumerator())
        using (var second = y.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var hasFirst = first.MoveNext();
                var hasSecond = second.MoveNext();
                if (hasFirst && !hasSecond)
                    return 1;
                if (hasSecond && !hasFirst)
                    return -1;
                if (!hasFirst && !hasSecond)
                    return 0;
                var comparison = comparer.Compare(first.Current, second.Current);
                if (comparison != 0)
                    return comparison;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then order the items in your collection using this comparer:

```
var query = dictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value, new SequenceComparer<int>());
```

If you want the items in the sequence to sort based on their ordered values, and the sequences are not already ordered, then you can add an ordering of the inner sequences into the query:

```
var query = dictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.OrderBy(x => x), 
    new SequenceComparer<int>());
```

Comment: What OrderBy call are you calling that takes in a `IEqualityComparer<T>`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Right, sorry, grabbed from the wrong source.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort dictionary values in separate list using a custom comparison method:

```
  static void Main()
  {
        var map = new Dictionary<object, IList<int>>();

        map.Add("item_1", new int[] { 2, 2, 4 });
        map.Add("item_2", new int[] { 1, 3, 4 });
        map.Add("item_3", new int[] { 2, 3, 4 });
        map.Add("item_4", new int[] { 1, 2});

        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<object, IList<int>>>(map);

        list.Sort(CompareSequences);


        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", item.Key, string.Join<int>("," , item.Value));
        }

  }



    static int CompareSequences(KeyValuePair<object, IList<int>> left, 
        KeyValuePair<object, IList<int>> right)
    {
         int count = Math.Min(left.Value.Count, right.Value.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            if (left.Value[i] < right.Value[i])
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (left.Value[i] > right.Value[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        if (right.Value.Count > count)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (left.Value.Count  > count)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

One difference with OrderBy() sorting is that sorting algorithm in List.Sort() is not stable. 
But it uses less memory and fewer temporary objects

Comment: Works, but doesn't use Linq as per the OP's request (PS: here's a [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6OhT0w) of it :) ).

Comment: True, I did not notice the Ling in the question, thanks for pointing me.