# sort a dictionary's keys based on its values; values represent arrays and sorting order varies - ascending/descending; c#

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I would like to sort a list of objects. The structure is a `Dictionary<object, double[]>` and looks like this:

```
    Dictionary<int, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<int, double[]>{
    {object1, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.30, 0.5}},
    {object4, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.30, 0.2}},
    {object3, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.30, 0.3}},
    {object2, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.50, 0.4}}
    };
```

The arrays should be ordered in different orders based on the index. i.e ascending for the 1st, 2nd and 4th index and descending for the 3rd index. So eventually, I should get:

```
object2, 0.02, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4
object4, 0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2
object3, 0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3
object1, 0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5
```

I 'm using the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982202/sort-a-dictionary-object-listint-c-sharp/64307850#64307850) as a starting point. What kind of adjustments should I make? Of course I understand that the method will not be generic (array length unrelated) anymore. I was considering creating a `bool[]` which has the same size as the `double[]`, where `True` stands for ascending sorting and `False` for descending, but Compare method strictly gets 2 arguments. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The OP wrote that he doesn't need a generic solution

Comment: @ЯрославВиталиевич what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: `How's your code going to know which keys are supposed to be sorted ascending and which ones descending` - you wrote this. I assume OP just wanted to make a Hardcoded comparer

Comment: Dear Pranav, as I said, i created bool[] = [True, True, False, True]. My intetnion was to use it as 3rd argument at Compare method. That as you know didn't work. I 'm kindly asking for hints/ideas on how to integrate this additional piece of information to the sorting algorithm. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, just try to use this comparer:

```
    public class SequenceComparer : IComparer<IList<double>>
    {
        public SequenceComparer(bool[] markers)
        {
            Markers = markers;
        }

        public bool[] Markers { get; }
        
        public int Compare(IList<double> x, IList<double> y)
        {
            //check for null
            if (x == null || y == null || Markers == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Null arrays are not valid");
            }

            //check identical count
            if (x.Count != y.Count || x.Count != Markers.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid count");
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            {
                if (x[i].Equals(y[i]))
                {
                   continue;
                }

                var comparisonResult = x[i] > y[i] ? 1 : -1;
                
                //if marker is false, invert comparisonResult
                return Markers[i] ? comparisonResult : comparisonResult * -1;
            }

            //Your arrays are identical, just skip
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

You can use any length arrays and regulate ordering direction with `bool[]` flags
Example of using:

```
var query = dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value, new SequenceComparer(new []{true, true, false, true}));
```

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what I had in mind; non-generic, integrated inside the Compare method. Thanks again.

Comment: Just updated `check identical count` condition. Please use the latest version

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Linq** library. Call `OrderBy` on the dictionary.

```
var x = dict.OrderBy(o => o.Value[0]).ThenBy(o => o.Value[1]).ThenBy(o => -o.Value[2]).ThenBy(o => o.Value[3]);
```

Full Code:

```
using System.Linq;
...........
public static void Main()
    {
        var object1 = 1;
        var object2 = 2;
        var object3 = 3;
        var object4 = 4;
        
        Dictionary<int, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<int, double[]>{
        {object1, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.30, 0.5}},
        {object4, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.30, 0.2}},
        {object3, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.30, 0.3}},
        {object2, new double[]{0.02, 0.10, 0.50, 0.4}}
        };
        
        var x = dict.OrderBy(o => o.Value[0]).ThenBy(o => o.Value[1]).ThenBy(o => -o.Value[2]).ThenBy(o => o.Value[3]);
        
        // write ordered values
        foreach (var d in x)
        {
            Console.Write(d.Key + ", [");
            foreach (var v in d.Value)
                Console.Write(v + ", ");
            Console.WriteLine("]");
        }
    }
```

Output

```
2, [0.02, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, ]
4, [0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, ]
3, [0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, ]
1, [0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, ]
```

Comment: thanks @Mike67. I am aware of this Linq syntax, but didn't know i could use -o.Value[2] to make it descending. thanks for the cherry on the top!

Comment: Linq's `ThenByDescending()` is also an option

Comment: great! even "cleaner"!